# PPTP VPN connects but does not have access to network resources

Tags: vpn, pptp, rras

I have a Windows server 2012 R2 which is connected to a router which is connected to modem. The server is also a domain controller and DNS server with the static ip address 192.168.0.201

1. Routing and Remote Access is set up on the server and VPN server is also set up. LAN and demand-dial routing is enabled
2. A static address pool is used for VPN client and the pool has no overlap with address pool by DHCP. Also on the client VPN setup, I cleared "use default gateway on remote network"
3. IPconfig /all from the server:

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DC-SERVER

Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : test.local

Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid

IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes

WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : test.local

PPP adapter :

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media unoperational

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : RAS (Dial In) Interface

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.0.36(Preferred)

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter NIC2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 11-97-36-C6-H7-XE

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ee80::973e:8e5f:ac05:512b%13(Preferred)

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.201(Preferred)

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 219191350

DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-09-5F-8E-86-94-10-98-63-Z6-B7-BD

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1

```
                                   127.0.0.1

                                   192.168.0.201
```

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

## 4. route print from the server

Interface List
 37...........................RAS (Dial In) Interface

13...11 97 36 C6 H7 XE ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2

1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1

===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table

===========================================================================

Active Routes:

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

```
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.201    266

    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
```

127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

```
  192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.201    266

192.168.0.201  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.201    266

192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.201    266

    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.201    266
```

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.201    266

===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:

Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric

## 0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1  Default

5. Nslookup from the VPN client:

DNS request timed out

```
timeout was 2 seconds.
```

Default server: unknown

Address: 192.168.0.201

6. ipconfig /all from the VPN client:

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : laptop2

Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :

Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid

IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

PPP adapter Integra PPTP:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : test PPTP

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.231(Preferred)

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.201

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 94-E9-79-82-36-43

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2605:6000:e984:f700:9bc:a0bf:1379:71b7(Preferred)

Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2605:6000:e984:f700:dd58:63bc:4c1:5cb5(Preferred)

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9bc:a0bf:1379:71b7%12(Preferred)

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.24(Preferred)

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, September 25, 2017 4:27:56 PM

Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, September 26, 2017 9:58:16 AM

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::9a6b:3dff:fee7:f7f7%12

```
                                   192.168.0.1
```

DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 76867961

DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-A4-63-4A-54-AB-3A-F4-E1-FE

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 209.18.47.62

```
                                   209.18.47.61
```

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

7. ping from the VPN client:
   ping 192.168.0.201:
   request timed out

ping www.google.com is successful

## 8.  route print from VPN client:

Interface List

8...54 ab 3a f4 e1 fe ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

21...96 e9 79 82 36 43 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter

48...........................Integra PPTP

12...94 e9 79 82 36 43 ......Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter

1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1

6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2

4...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3

20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

===========================================================================

## IPv4 Route Table

Active Routes:

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

```
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.24     55

50.84.123.102  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.24     56

    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
```

127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

```
  192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.24    311

  192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.0.230    192.168.0.231     46

 192.168.0.24  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.24    311

192.168.0.231  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.231    301

192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.24    311

    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.24    311

    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.231    301
```

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.24    311

## 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.231    301

Persistent Routes:

## None

Comment: BTW: firewalls on both VPN client and VPN server are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

After checking everything I can and finally I discovered the latest Windows update KB4038792 was causing the problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4038792/windows-8-1-update-kb4038792

After having it removed (without doing anything else), PPTP works and also L2TP works as well.